# How to subtract totals of 2 different groupings of the same column per month

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2, sum

I am writing a query in which I am supposed to subtract total revenue by discounts per month. Problem is that there are multiple codes which represent either revenue or discounts.

To illustrate exactly what I mean, please see the following example.

```
 Month       Code         Amount
 May         4001         $50.05
 May         4002         $49.95
 May         6005         $15.00
 May         6006         $5.00
 March       4003         $65.00
```

Codes for revenue are 4001, 4002 and 4003. Discounts are 6005 and 6006.

In the end I should be seeing:

```
 Month       TotalRevenue      TotalDiscount       Total
 May         $100.00           $20.00              $80.00
 March       $65.00            $0.00               $65.00
```

I have tried CASE but it tells me I can only use 1 argument. I have also tried creating a sub query in the select statement, but I can't seem to be able to use 2 SUM statements (1 in main and 1 in sub). I guess it would work if I had a possibility to use 'join' but there is nothing to join it with.

Comment: Show us some of those tries

Comment: How big is the list of codes?  Just the 5 described above or are there many more?

Comment: There are 19 revenue codes and 8 discount codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first issue is to construct your query so that the Discount Codes are distinguished from the Revenue Codes.  If you have table(s) containing the Codes (either one combined Codes table with an indicator to distinguish the two types, or separate tables), this table (or tables) should be used.

Since it's hard to tell the full set of Codes from your question, let's just pretend that Codes 6000-6999 are Discounts and all others are Revenue.  Then a query that produces your desired results could look like this:

```
select Month, 
Revenue = sum(
    case when Code between 6000 and 6999 then 
        0
    else
       Amount
    end
),
Discounts = sum(
    case when Code between 6000 and 6999 then 
        Amount
    else
       0
    end
),
Total = sum(
    case when Code between 6000 and 6999 then 
        -1 * Amount
    else
        Amount
    end
)
from MyTable
group by Month
```

Depending on whatever your actual criteria is for distinguishing the two types of codes, you just need to change the `case` statements to match and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you pretty close to the desired result:

**Setup (it would be really appreciated if provided in the question :) )**

```
-- drop table Code
create table Code
(
    Code INT,
    IsRevenue BIT
)

insert into Code VALUES (4001, 1), (4002, 1), (4003, 1), (6005, 0), (6006, 0)
GO

create table MonthData
(
    TheMonth VARCHAR(16),
    Code INT,
    Amount NUMERIC(18, 2)
)
GO

insert into MonthData values ('May', 4001, 50.05),  ('May', 4002, 49.95), 
     ('May', 6005, 15.00), ('May', 6006, 5.00), ('March', '4003', 65.00)
GO

select * from MonthData
GO
```

**The query:**

```
SELECT TheMonth, 
    SUM((CASE WHEN C.IsRevenue = 1 THEN MD.Amount ELSE -MD.Amount END)) AS TotalRevenue
FROM MonthData MD
    JOIN Code C ON C.Code = MD.Code
GROUP BY TheMonth
```